# Check when smoothScrollToPosition has finished

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I would like to check when `smoothScrollToPosition` has finished scrolling back to the first item of `recyclerview`. I tried doing it like this which only works while smoothScrollToPosition is still scrolling:

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView,new RecyclerView.State(), 0);
if (!recyclerView.getLayoutManager().isSmoothScrolling()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Scrolling has ended.");
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I use `onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)` method for tracking scrolling state. The method to initiate scroll looks like this:

```
private void scrollToPosition(int position){
    recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
}
```

And here is the listener:

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
       @Override
       public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
           switch (newState) {
               case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                   //we reached the target position
                   recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                   break;
           }
       }
   };
```

So, when recyclerView reaches SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, that means it has finished scrolling. Don't forget to remove listener in this state, so it won't trigger on the next scroll.

Comment: RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener just adds listener in a List. So, i guess we may add the same listener several times, so it will be duplicated.So, if scrollToPosition will be called from some click listener, we must remove old onScrollListener in case it wasn't removed in onScrollStateChanged, because the desired SCROLL_STATE_IDLE did not happen yet.

Answer (score -2):

There is a listener for it:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

```
void onScrolled (RecyclerView recyclerView, 
                int dx, 
                int dy)
```

Callback method to be invoked when the RecyclerView has been scrolled. **This will be called after the scroll has completed.**

Comment: This method is called multiple times while recyclerView is scrolling.