# How to prevent touches prematurely stopping smoothScroll in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am using an `Adapter` to fill a `RecyclerView` with numerous `CardView` layouts (horizontally). Each `CardView` has a `Button` at the bottom of the layout, which when pressed prompts the call:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(x, y);
```

This scrolls horizontally to the next card as expected, unless the user touches the screen as it is scrolling. I have attempted disabling the `TouchEvent` for the `RecyclerView` and the `CardView` to no avail.

I obviously cannot rely on a user to not touch the screen during this scrolling animation, so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to why the scrolling is halted prematurely and how I can stop it.

[image: img]

Thanks.

Comment: You can implement a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` - disable recyclerview touch until scroll ends - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51262424/5550161

Comment: @HB. Disabling touch on the RecyclerView doesn't prevent it from stopping prematurely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55849546/5550161

Comment: @HB. Still no luck. I don't think anything will, so thanks for trying anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is `onInterceptTouchEvent`

if you add listener to recyclerView this way:

```
    addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
        override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    })
```

1. if it is return true you can't scroll recyclerView manually (programmatically you can)
2. if it is return true scrolling is stopped/interrupted

this option worked for me (add this to recyclerView with previous code snippet (to prevent manual scrolling) to prevent scrolling interrupt on touch):

```
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (layoutManager?.isSmoothScrolling == true || scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
        return true
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e)
}

override fun onTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (layoutManager?.isSmoothScrolling == true || scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
        return true
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(e)
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem in the end, but can’t remember how for the life of me now. I know that my solution was different to yours, but I think yours undoubtedly would’ve helped at the time. Thanks for posting and hopefully it helps someone in future!

Answer (score 0):

Disable user interactions before the scroll and reenable them a little after. I would use window flags:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(x, y);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   public void run(){
      getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
   }
}, 500);
```