# RecyclerView onclick - scroll to that item and show faded background

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am recently implement an onclick event to scroll to that particular `ViewHolder` and trigger a faded background.

However, the problem occurs when `RecyclerView` have lots of item, and the selected `ViewHolder` is not populated, hence the ``` ViewHolder`` that out of the ``` RecyclerView``` is not highlighted.

```
// Function to show a faded background for OnClick item
fun fadedBackground(view: View, context: Context) {
      val colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(
          view,
          "backgroundColor" /*view attribute name*/,
          ArgbEvaluator(),
          ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.list_item_selected_state) /*from color*/,
          ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.list_item_normal_state) /*to color*/
      ).apply {
          duration = 5000
          startDelay = 200
      }
      colorFade.start()
  }
```

```
val rvItem = chatRecycler.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)  
 if (rvItem != null) {   
        // item that not require scrolling
        fadedBackground(
             rvItem.itemView.message_wrapper,
              this@ChatActivity
        )
} else {
    // item that require scrolling, set background when scrolling stop
    // chatRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(replyInt)
                                   
    val viewholder = chatRecycler.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(replyInt)  <-- ALWAYS RETURN NULL
                               
    if(viewholder != null) {
       fadedBackground(
           aa.itemView.message_wrapper,
           this@ChatActivity
       )
     }
}
```

My question is,

1. Is my apporach correct? Because I done all these in `Activity` instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter`.
2. Why `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()` always returns null even after I called `smoothScrollToPosition()`?

Answer (score 1):

> Why findViewHolderForAdapterPosition() always returns null even after I called smoothScrollToPosition()?

It is because smoothScrollToPosition actually runs the animation. So, you have to at least provide delay or check if the `smoothScroll` has finished its job.

See here:
[Check when smoothScrollToPosition has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261327/check-when-smoothscrolltoposition-has-finished)

> Is my apporach correct? Because I done all these in Activity instead of RecyclerView.Adapter.

I prefer you run the animation on the `adapter.onBindViewHolder`

In the activity, you can do `smoothScrollToPosition` and the give the flag to the item. In `onBindViewHolder`, you check the flag, if the flag is true, you run the animation, and then reset the flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but how can i run the flag in ```onBindViewHolder``` to highlight that selected viewHolder?

Comment: You can create new variable to store if the item given at the position is animating or not. This variable can be in form of map, list, or attribute of the item.

For example, val isPositionAnimating = listOf<Boolean>(). Store this in Adapter. Then in onBindViewHolder, check the list of the position.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a ScrollListener to RecyclerView like this

```
chatRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
chatRecycler.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState : Int) {
         when (newState) {
              RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                  //When we reached the target position
                  recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this)
                  //Animate background color when recyclerview stops scrolling
                  val rvItem = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
                  if (rvItem != null) {
                        fadedBackground(
                           rvItem.itemView.message_wrapper,
                           this@ChatActivity
                        )
                   }

              }
         }
     }
 })
```